# What is the best way to organize Controller when inject Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What I have:

```
.factory
.controller
ui-router
```

I'm wondering how it's better to organize controllers.

Example:

```js
.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, Factory) {

      Factory.getSmth1().then(function(res) {
        $scope.get1 = response;
      });

      Factory.getSmth2().then(function(res) {
        $scope.get2 = response;
      });

      // And So on 3,4,5,6-10



    }
```

Or it's better to use ui-router resolve:

```js
 .state('state', {
       url: '/state',
       templateUrl: '/view.html',
       controller: 'mainCtrl',
       resolve: {
         get1: function(Factory) {
           return Factory.get1();
         },

         get2: function(Factory) {
           return Factory.get2();
         },

         // and SO ON
       })



.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, get1, get2) {

         $scope.get1 = get1;

         $scope.ger2 = get2;


})
```

Maybe any another methods?
Is there any difference?
What is better?

Comment: Personally I have service calls in the controller, because I also have the states configured in a seperate file, so this way I have all of the functionality of the controller in one place. This is my preference though, so it may not be the best option.

Comment: `app.config()` should only store settings and definitions for states.  It shouldn't be responsible to getting and resolving values.  You should isolate that responsibility to the controller.

Comment: KKKKKKKK - but what for it's have resolve opportunity?

Comment: Somewhat contrary to the above, I like using the ui-router resolves. It ensures that all the data is received before the controller/view are instantiated/rendered. Keeping those requests outside of your controller makes the unit tests for the controller's **much** simpler. If your resolve code is complex (more than just a 1 liner), you can put it in a service and just reference it from the config/routing file. This allows you to write tests for the resolve code as well.

Comment: The question is broad and opinion-based. There's no 'best way'. The main practical benefit of the resolver is that `get1`  is injected as resolved promise value. As regards testing, it makes controller specs slimmer and routing specs fatter, so it's a tie.

Comment: Thanks all you guys!